# Overriding Swiping Actions on a UITableView over UIPageController VC segues

Tags: uitableview, swift, uipageviewcontroller

In **swift**, i'm currently working on segueing my VC's using a `UIPageViewController`, where when you swipe left or right it changes the VC. In one of my `View Controllers`, a table view exists, where if you swipe on the row there are options. My problem is, when I swipe on the row of the table, it changes to my View Controller. I want to override this so that it shows row actions before VC swiping. My code below is the first VC. PS: If you need my Code for my tableviews please comment for it! Thanks

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    var myViewControllers = Array(count: 4, repeatedValue:UIViewController())

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let pvc = segue.destinationViewController as UIPageViewController

        pvc.dataSource = self

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

        var vc0 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as UIViewController
        var vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as UIViewController
        var vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as UIViewController
        var vc3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FourthViewController") as UIViewController

        self.myViewControllers = [vc0, vc1, vc2, vc3]

        pvc.setViewControllers([myViewControllers[1]], direction:.Forward, animated:false, completion:nil)

        println("Loaded")
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!+1
        if currentIndex >= self.myViewControllers.count {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers[currentIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!-1
        if currentIndex < 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers[currentIndex]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the tableView takes all the space in your view? let's try with

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
}
```

Comment: Yes, the table takes up the width and almost the total height of the VC, although, when i paste that function in, it says, "Method does not override any method from its superclass". if i remove the "override" with the func, it doesnt change anything.